# How to make Material-UI Dialog resizable

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a project that requires a dialog to be resizable and draggable. Material-UI Dialog documentation has steps on how to make it draggable. I want to find out the resizable part. Any suggestions on how to?

Sample code can be found [here](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#DraggableDialog.tsx).

UPDATE:

Functional and typescript version of [@Khabir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7119904/khabir)'s answer below

```
    import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
    import Dialog from '@material-ui/core/Dialog'
    import DialogActions from '@material-ui/core/DialogActions'
    import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent'
    import DialogContentText from '@material-ui/core/DialogContentText'
    import DialogTitle from '@material-ui/core/DialogTitle'
    import Paper, { PaperProps } from '@material-ui/core/Paper'
    import { makeStyles, Theme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'
    import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
    import React from 'react'
    import Draggable from 'react-draggable'
    import { ResizableBox } from 'react-resizable'

    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
        resizable: {
            position: 'relative',
            '& .react-resizable-handle': {
                position: 'absolute',    
                width: 20,  
                height: 20,   
                bottom: 0,
                right: 0,
                background:"url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2IDYiIHN0eWxlPSJiYWNrZ3JvdW5kLWNvbG9yOiNmZmZmZmYwMCIgeD0iMHB4IiB5PSIwcHgiIHdpZHRoPSI2cHgiIGhlaWdodD0iNnB4Ij48ZyBvcGFjaXR5PSIwLjMwMiI+PHBhdGggZD0iTSA2IDYgTCAwIDYgTCAwIDQuMiBMIDQgNC4yIEwgNC4yIDQuMiBMIDQuMiAwIEwgNiAwIEwgNiA2IEwgNiA2IFoiIGZpbGw9IiMwMDAwMDAiLz48L2c+PC9zdmc+')",
                'background-position': 'bottom right',
                padding: '0 3px 3px 0',
                'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
                'background-origin': 'content-box',
                'box-sizing': 'border-box',
                cursor: 'se-resize',
            },
        },
    }))

    const PaperComponent = (props: PaperProps) => {
        return (
            <Draggable
                handle="#draggable-dialog-title"
                cancel={'[class*="MuiDialogContent-root"]'}
            >
                <Paper {...props} />
            </Draggable>
        )
    }

    export const DialogComponent = () => {
        const [open, setOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false)
        const handleClickOpen = () => {
            setOpen(true)
        }

        const handleClose = () => {
            setOpen(false)
        }

        const classes = useStyles()

        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={handleClickOpen}>Open dd form dialog</Button>
                {open && (
                    <Dialog
                        open={true}
                        onClose={handleClose}
                        maxWidth={false}
                        PaperComponent={PaperComponent}
                        aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title"
                    >
                        <ResizableBox
                            height={400}
                            width={600}
                            className={classes.resizable}
                        >
                            <DialogTitle
                                style={{ cursor: 'move' }}
                                id="draggable-dialog-title"
                            >
                                Subscribe
                            </DialogTitle>

                            <DialogContent>
                                <DialogContentText>
                                    To subscribe to this website, please enter your email address here. We will send updates occasionally.
                                </DialogContentText>

                                <TextField
                                    autoFocus
                                    margin="dense"
                                    id="name"
                                    label="Email Address"
                                    type="email"
                                    fullWidth
                                />
                            </DialogContent>

                            <DialogActions>
                                <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                                    Cancel
                                </Button>
                                <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                                    Subscribe
                                </Button>
                            </DialogActions>
                        </ResizableBox>
                    </Dialog>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

typescript 3.8.3
@material-ui/core 4.9.7

Comment: If you could provide us a code snippet of your current attempt that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well done (for adding the Typescript version) +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi I merged two features together. please check the example. It supports both drag and resize.

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Draggable from "react-draggable";
import {withStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@material-ui/core/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import {ResizableBox} from "react-resizable";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";

const styles = theme => ({
    resizable: {
        position: "relative",
        "& .react-resizable-handle": {
            position: "absolute",
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
            background:
                "url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA2IDYiIHN0eWxlPSJiYWNrZ3JvdW5kLWNvbG9yOiNmZmZmZmYwMCIgeD0iMHB4IiB5PSIwcHgiIHdpZHRoPSI2cHgiIGhlaWdodD0iNnB4Ij48ZyBvcGFjaXR5PSIwLjMwMiI+PHBhdGggZD0iTSA2IDYgTCAwIDYgTCAwIDQuMiBMIDQgNC4yIEwgNC4yIDQuMiBMIDQuMiAwIEwgNiAwIEwgNiA2IEwgNiA2IFoiIGZpbGw9IiMwMDAwMDAiLz48L2c+PC9zdmc+')",
            "background-position": "bottom right",
            padding: "0 3px 3px 0",
            "background-repeat": "no-repeat",
            "background-origin": "content-box",
            "box-sizing": "border-box",
            cursor: "se-resize"
        }
    }
});

function PaperComponent(props) {
    return (
        <Draggable handle="#draggable-dialog-title" cancel={'[class*="MuiDialogContent-root"]'}>
            <Paper {...props} />
        </Draggable>
    );
}

class DraggableResizableDialog extends React.Component {
    state = {
        open: false
    };

    handleClickOpen = () => {
        this.setState({open: true});
    };

    handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({open: false});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.handleClickOpen}>Open dd form dialog</Button>
                {this.state.open && (
                    <Dialog
                        open={true}
                        onClose={this.handleClose}
                        maxWidth={false}
                        PaperComponent={PaperComponent}
                        aria-labelledby="draggable-dialog-title"
                    >
                        <ResizableBox
                            height={400}
                            width={600}
                            className={this.props.classes.resizable}
                        >
                            <DialogTitle style={{ cursor: 'move' }} id="draggable-dialog-title">Subscribe</DialogTitle>
                            <DialogContent>
                                <DialogContentText>
                                    To subscribe to this website, please enter your email address
                                    here. We will send updates occasionally.
                                </DialogContentText>
                                <TextField
                                    autoFocus
                                    margin="dense"
                                    id="name"
                                    label="Email Address"
                                    type="email"
                                    fullWidth
                                />
                            </DialogContent>
                            <DialogActions>
                                <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
                                    Cancel
                                </Button>
                                <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
                                    Subscribe
                                </Button>
                            </DialogActions>
                        </ResizableBox>
                    </Dialog>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(DraggableResizableDialog);
```

**Source:** [Draggable](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/) [Resizable](https://codesandbox.io/s/lp8q9r92x9?file=/demo.js)

Comment: will try this out.

Comment: Both of these function don't work together simultaneously, I don't know why this answer has been excepted.

Comment: @Mob_Abominator I always run my example before giving answer. it worked on my pc on that time. perhaps you have any issue in your side.

Comment: @Khabir, Yeah it works but it's not usable, With Paper component you can't drag and resize at the same time, when you try to resize it, it also starts dragging around. You musn't have tested it properly. Individually they work fine but not together.

Comment: @Mob_Abominator I haven't tried the answer here, here's a working example showing Dragging and Resizing for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/draggable-resizable-material-demo-3oxu96?file=/demo.js